# Second HDD with Ubuntu causes Windows to "searching preconfigured driver folders" indefinitely

Tags: hard-drive, multi-boot

I normally use Windows 7 and recently got a new HDD to install Ubuntu with. I was able to boot windows by default and switch to Ubuntu by manually choosing the booting hard disk. This was all fine until the Ubuntu disk failed*, and it has not even been one month since I purchased it.

*It stopped showing up on the boot devices dialog one day and attempts to change sata cables, sata ports, use an enclosure, using 2 other different pcs all failed to pick up the disk.

I now have a replacement hard disk up and running the same way, but I am paranoid that I am doing something that is causing the hardware to fail somehow.

I have just booted into windows the first time after this replacement hdd was loaded with Ubuntu, and I am seeing this box:

[image]

It's been doing this for a while now. Can this be in any way damaging to the hard disk?

Comment: It shouldn't harm anything, this is just a read action as far as I know it is searching for a driver for the device and not actually reading the hard drive... Other's have noted this can take 10-20 minutes in some cases.

Comment: It did disappear eventually but I did not catch exactly when. It seemed to be more than an hour. IIRC the dialog appeared after windows reported that "your device is installed and ready for use". Curious why it would continue searching.